# Importing CSV file to teradata using SQL ASSISTANT

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am importing a CSV file to teradata using SQL ASSISTANT, there is a date column, the dates are in the formats d/m/yyyy,d/mm/yyyy,dd/m/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy. How can i get all of them from the CSV file to teradata in the format dd/mm/yyyy using the SQL ASSISTANT.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Cast(RegExp_Replace(?,'\b([\d])\b', '0\1') AS DATE FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

The RegEx pads single digits with a leading zero, then it can be safely casted.

SQL Assistant is not the best/fastest way to import, don't forget to set the *Maximum Batch size for simple Imports* option to 999 to increase speed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that as soon as the on going system maintenance is over. This is data that was sent to me in the excel format to use and update certain columns on a table in our database. So I'm using SQL Assistant to import it to a table I've created so that I can use in my where clause. Is there a better way you can suggest? Thanks

Comment: If it's a one-time load and not a large file (Excel) you can easily use SQLA. Of course, it would be easier to load if the data was created using the correct date format :-)

Comment: One of the columns in the file I'm importing is coming in the format 05-MAY-20 03.01.14.575144 PM, that is the month is initialized with 3 letters . When creating the target table, how should the target column be defined? Thanks

Comment: You need a TIMESTAMP(6) and a matching format, `Cast(? AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'dd-mmm-yyBhh.mi.ss.s(6)BT')`, depending on some server setting a two digit year might result in 19xx, switching to Oracle syntax `To_Timestamp(?, 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss.ff6 PM')` fixes this

Comment: now i am having invalid date, the date columns are in the 7th and 8th positions, so I simply replaced the '?' with the 'cast', but when I try to insert, it says invalid date

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, you are really an angel. Teradata didn't take Cast(RegExp_Replace(?,'\b([\d])\b', '0\1') AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy') so I changed to Cast(RegExp_Replace(?,'\b([\d])\b', '0\1') AS DATE FORMAT 'mm-dd-yyyy')